# modal flow OUT issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I spent some time today editing a form that flashes into the screen. I changed the size of the form and did a bunch of things to make the form suit my needs.

However, when I exit the form -- on the fade "out" -- the form goes back to the wonky old setup.....which looks pretty bad. I'm looking for a way to upload my edits to the form as well as the form that fades out.

Kinda tough to explain, so here's the example:

http://www.fishingreports.com - if you click the big button "CREATE AN ACCOUNT" you will see the form I'm talking about. And if you exit the form, you'll see the ugly fade-out I'm talking about as well.

Thanks All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed your CSS and added a `modal.fade.in { width: 392px }` but you never changed the fading out css.

On your web.css, remove line 136 (it's a duplicate)

Change

```
Line 139: modal.hide.fade.in { width:392px;} -> modal.hide.fade { width:392px;}
Line 141: modal.fade.in {} -> modal.hide.fade {}
```

and that should fix your issue

Comment: I updated my answer. You have a couple duplicates, and it isn't calling `.out` like I though it was.

Comment: Awesome dude - thanks! So, it appears what I was doing wrong was specificying .in/.out when I just needed to make a rule for EVERYTHING? Basically, don't do .in/.out unless I need to have a special rule that doesn't apply elsewhere.